# Haskell Scotty Webserver send a text response

Tags: haskell, scotty

I get a GET request and want to send a text message as a response to it.I have the following code but am getting the following error

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

import Data.Monoid (mconcat) 

main = scotty 4000 $ do
middleware logStdoutDev

get "/" $ do
    beam<- param "q"
    text $ "The message which I want to send"
```

The error I am getting when I try to run the server is

```
No instance for (Parsable t0) arising from a use of ‘param’
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Parsable () -- Defined in ‘scotty-0.9.1:Web.Scotty.Action’
  instance Parsable Bool
    -- Defined in ‘scotty-0.9.1:Web.Scotty.Action’
  instance Parsable Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
    -- Defined in ‘scotty-0.9.1:Web.Scotty.Action’
  ...plus 9 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block: beam <- param "q"
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { beam <- param "q";
        text $ "The message I want to send" }’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  get "/"
  $ do { beam <- param "q";
         text $ "The message I want to send" }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`param` has type `Parsable a => Text -> ActionM a`. As you can see, `a` is polymorphic and only requires an instance of `Parsable a`. It's the return type as well. But as you can see [in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.1/docs/Web-Scotty.html#g:8) Parsable has several instances available! GHC doesn't know what you want, hence the ambiguous error. You will need to specify a type annotation letting GHC know what you want. But anyway, let's write the code

`beam <- param "q" :: ActionM Text`

should do the trick. Now `beam` should have be a `Text`. But maybe you are expecting your parameter to be an integer so something like

`beam <- param "q" :: ActionM Integer`

can work as well.

Comment: Do I need to import a module?Getting this error
 Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Text’
when I do beam <- param "q" :: ActionM Text

Comment: `Text` comes from `Data.Text`

Comment: Data.Text gives this error.

    Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
                with actual type ‘Text’
    NB: ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
          is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy’
        ‘Text’ is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘beam’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: text $ beam

Apologies if its a noob question. Just introduced to wonderful world of haskell

Comment: NP :). Don't import `Data.Text`, import `Data.Text.Lazy`.

Comment: Note that you don't always need to add an explicit type. You're just getting this error because you aren't actually using the value of the parameter anywhere, so the compiler can't infer its type. Normally it could work it out from the context in which it's used.